# Cython basic build still failing

Tags: python, c

I am using python 2.7.6 and am on Windows 7 x64 Here is the entry point display for my python:

```
>python
Python 2.7.6 [MSC v.1800 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

So I am using all 32bit binaries. I am trying to compile the fibonacci demo/tutorial from the 2013 Sci Py talk on using Cython showing [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKCjsRDffXo). You can download the tutorial files [here](http://public.enthought.com/~ksmith/scipy2013_cython/) ( unpack the tutorial files  and go into `~/demo/fib/` ).

I have installed Cython using `pip install cython` which is a success. I tried to compile the python `.pyx` using

```
>python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compilers=mingw32

running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    ext_modules = exts,
  File "~\Python\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "~\Python\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "~\Python\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "~\Python\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 163,
in run
    _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
  File "~\Python\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 306, in run
    force=self.force)
  File "~\Python\Lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1004, in new_compiler
    return klass(None, dry_run, force)
  File "~\Python\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 309, in __init__
    CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)
  File "~\Python\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 152, in __init__
    self.dll_libraries = get_msvcr()
  File "~\Python\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 82, in get_msvcr
    raise ValueError("Unknown MS Compiler version %s " % msc_ver)
ValueError: Unknown MS Compiler version 1800
```

I checked and modified `cygwinccompiler.py` and saw and made the following changes:

```
def get_msvcr():
    """Include the appropriate MSVC runtime library if Python was built
    with MSVC 7.0 or later.
    """
    msc_pos = sys.version.find('MSC v.')
    if msc_pos != -1:
        msc_ver = sys.version[msc_pos+6:msc_pos+10]
        if msc_ver == '1300':
            # MSVC 7.0
            return ['msvcr70']
        elif msc_ver == '1310':
            # MSVC 7.1
            return ['msvcr71']
        elif msc_ver == '1400':
            # VS2005 / MSVC 8.0
            return ['msvcr80']
        elif msc_ver == '1500':
            # VS2008 / MSVC 9.0
            return ['msvcr90']
        elif msc_ver == '1800':     # I added this!!!
            # VS2013 / MSVC 12.0    # I added this!!!
            return ['msvcr120']     # I added this!!!
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unknown MS Compiler version %s " % msc_ver)
```

since apparently `msc_ver == '1800'` (the version of msvc my python was compiled with) is the 2013 visual studio c compiler, and reffered to as `msvcr120` from some quick google searches. So I installed that:

[image]

Now, however, I get the following cython DLL error.

```
>python setup.py build_ext --compiler=mingw32
running build_ext
failed to import Cython: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
error: Cython does not appear to be installed
```

Where is it looking for the DLL's? What DLL's does it need? Why isn't it finding any the DLL's after installing the 5+ versions of MSVC redistributable packages ( I've struggled with getting python to find msvc compilers in general since day one of using python a good while ago now. true dependency hell. anyway...)

My `PYTHONHOME` environment variable is set, but I don't have `PYTHONPATH` set to anything.

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this?

what do?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I am using 32-bit python 2.7.9 on Windows 7 x64 and it says "Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32", so I don't know how you got an older version built with MS Compiler version 1800. From my understanding Python 2.7.x are all built with VS2008 and need that 32-bit version of the C runtime DLL installed for it. I'd trying reinstalling Python.

Comment: @martineau actually i'm not sure why i have 2.7.6, as a I installed recently a 2.7.9 version which is confusing as to why i'm not seeing that version. So I will reinstall later. But, I also tried on my laptop which has 2.7.9 and it worked! I dont' really know what's actually wrong with my 2.7.6 version though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like something went awry in my installation of python, as user @martineau pointed out. Python 2.7.9 is built using `msvc_ver = 1500`, or Visual Studio 2008, so why I'd have and older version of Python ( 2.7.6 ) which  uses a later compiler is not clear. I tried using a clean 2.7.9 installation on my other computer, and was able to successfully compile, without modifying `cygwinccompiler.py`.

Answer (score 0):

from https://bugs.python.org/msg251758
go and open https://bugs.python.org/file40608/patch.diff
do the changes described there to your `C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py`.
then do also the changes described in https://github.com/philpraxis/pysctp/issues/16#issuecomment-118885607 to your cygwinccompiler.py

in case you want to use gcc:

edit your `%USERPROFILE%/pydistutils.cfg` to have sg. like this

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32
; compiler=cygwin
```

make sure you have a mingw gcc in your path

Comment: happened to answer a different question in the end but it's related slightly so I let it be

Answer (score 0):

Corrected similar problem by just commenting out all (two) lines with occurrences of get_msvcr() in cygwinccompiler.py (and one "else:" line also). After this I had successfully compiled and installed and used `marisa-trie` by pip on Windows 10 / Python 3.5 / mingw32:

```
pip install marisa-trie
Collecting marisa-trie
  Using cached marisa-trie-0.7.2.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: marisa-trie
  Running setup.py install for marisa-trie ... done
Successfully installed marisa-trie-0.7.2
```